# How many different values can that sum take?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{100} $ be a permutation of $1,2,\dots,100.$ How many different values does the sum $ x_1+2x_2+\cdots+100x_{100}$ take?

Comment: It seems, that if you have sequence $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ as permutation of $1,2,...,n$, and take sum $x_1+2x_2+...+nx_n$, then you'll obtain $$\dfrac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{6}+1$$ different values of this sum. So, for $n=100$ I expect $166651$ different values.

Comment: @ Oleg567 : Calculations confirm that. How to prove it?

Comment: Perhaps starting point is that **smallest** sum is $$1\cdot n + 2 (n-1)+3(n-2)\cdots+n\cdot 1,$$ **largest** sum is $$1\cdot1+2\cdot2+\cdots+n\cdot n.$$ And that there are no **gaps** between/among them.

Comment: Why are there no gaps between these values?

Comment: Hmm, that is the most interesting question. Don't know yet. Maybe to consider some neighboring permutations etc...

Comment: @Oleg567: It doesn't work out for all $n$, in any case.  For instance, for $n=3$ the range is $10\ldots 14$, but there is a gap at $12$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx, yes, I needed to say "$n\ge 4$".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ be a permutations of $1,2,\dots,n.$ $(n\ge 4)$.

Then there are

$$
\dfrac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{6}+1
$$
different values of sums $ x_1+2x_2+\cdots+nx_n$.

Smallest value is 
$$v_n = 1\cdot n + 2(n-1)+3(n-2)+\cdots+n\cdot 1 = \sum_{j=1}^{n}j(n+1-j)=\dfrac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6},$$
largest value is
$$
V_n = 1\cdot 1+2\cdot 2+\cdots+n\cdot n = \sum_{j=1}^nj^2= \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
$$

---

Let's prove that there are no "gaps" between $v_n$ and $V_n$.

We'll use math. induction.

**0)** There are no "gaps" for $n=4$.
Really, 
$(4,3,2,1)\rightarrow 20$;
$(4,2,3,1)\rightarrow 21$;
 
$(3,4,1,2)\rightarrow 22$;
$(3,2,4,1)\rightarrow 23$;
$(4,1,2,3)\rightarrow 24$;
$(3,1,4,2)\rightarrow 25$; ... (other cases - symmetrically).

**1)** Suppose that there are no "gaps" for some $n=n_0$.

**2)** Now prove that there are no "gaps" for $n=n_0+1$:

**2.a)** all sums of vectors $(n_0+1, x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n_0})$ 
have form
$$
1(n_0+1)+2x_1+3x_2+\cdots+(n_0+1)x_{n_0} \\= n_0+1+(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n_0})+(x_1+2x_2+\cdots+n_0 x_{n_0})
$$
and fill values from 
$$
n_0+1+\dfrac{n_0(n_0+1)}{2}+\dfrac{n_0(n_0+1)(n_0+2)}{6} = \dfrac{(n_0+1)(n_0+2)(n_0+3)}{6}
= v_{n_0+1}$$
to
$$
n_0+1+\dfrac{n_0(n_0+1)}{2}+\dfrac{n_0(n_0+1)(2n_0+1)}{6} = \dfrac{2n_0^2+4n_0+6}{6} 
$$
without "gaps";

**2.b)** all sums of vectors $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n_0},n_0+1)$ 
have form
$$
x_1+2x_2+\cdots+n_0x_{n_0}+(n_0+1)(n_0+1) \\= (x_1+2x_2+\cdots+n_0 x_{n_0}) + (n_0+1)^2
$$
and fill values from 
$$
\dfrac{n_0(n_0+1)(n_0+2)}{6} + (n_0+1)^2 = \dfrac{n_0^2+8n_0+6}{6}
$$
to
$$
V_{n_0}+(n_0+1)^2 = \dfrac{(n_0+1)(n_0+2)(2n_0+3)}{6}=V_{n_0+1}.
$$
without "gaps".

**2.c)** It remains to show that upper bound of **2.a)** is not less than lower bound of **2.b)**. It is so, since 
$$
n_0\ge 4\\ 
\Downarrow \\
n_0^2 \ge 4n_0 \\
\Downarrow \\
2n_0^2 \ge n_0^2+4n_0 \\
\Downarrow \\
2n_0^2 +4n_0+6\ge n_0^2+8n_0+6.
$$

---

And apply it for $n=100$.

Comment: Nice solution Oleg. This is basically a special representation of $ A + \ldots + n \cdot A $ where $ A$ is all the integers from one to $ n $ (of size $ n! $). I wonder if there are other choices for the representation that would make this problem more interesting.